# How to show error message on each input type field in nodejs using express-validator

Tags: node.js, express

```
I am begginer in nodejs and I am using express-validator library to validate form.
```

I want to display error message seprately to each input type field,
 not group wise.
 Currently my code shows the error in group like

```
Name is required!
Email is required!
Email is wrong!
Mobile is required!
```

========================================================================

**Controller Code**

```
employeeController.saveEmployee = function(req,res){
    var employeeData = req.body;
    // Start Validation
    req.checkBody('employeeName','Name is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('employeeEmail','Email is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('employeeEmail','Email is wrong!').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('employeeMobile','Mobile is required!').notEmpty();

    req.sanitize('employeeName').trim();
    req.sanitize('employeeName').escape();
    // End Validation
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    console.log(errors);
    if(!errors){
        var employee = new Employee({
            name : req.body.employeeName,
            email : req.body.employeeEmail,
            mobile : req.body.employeemobile,
        });
        employee.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('User inserted successfully');
            res.redirect('/employee-list');
        });
    }else{
        console.log(employeeData.employeeName);
        res.render('employee/add-employee',{
            errors : errors,
            employeeData : employeeData
        });
    }
};
```

**View template**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Add Employee Profile</h3>
            <h5 class='text-aqua pull-right' style='margin-top: 0px;'>
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='' class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>&nbsp;Back</a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <p>
            <% if(errors){ %>
                <ul>
                <% for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){ %>
                    <li> <%= errors[i].msg %> </li>
                <% } %>
                </ul>
             <% } %>
        </p>
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method = 'post' action = '/save-employee'>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                        <input type='text' name='employeeName' id='employeeName' value='<%= employeeData.employeeName %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Name'>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 
                        <input type='text' name='employeeEmail' id='employeeEmail' value='<%= employeeData.employeeEmail %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Email'>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Mobile</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 
                        <input type='text' name='employeeMobile' id='employeeMobile' value='<%= employeeData.employeeMobile %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Mobile'>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="callout" id='message-container' style='display:none;'></div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type='submit' name='saveEmployeeProfile' class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your errors are shown separately, add example of your desired output, please.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want output like this, please click on image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJryi.jpg

Comment: What's your template engine?

Comment: I am using ejs template engine.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so what you have to do - is separate errors.
Your controller file:

```
employeeController.saveEmployee = function(req,res){
    const nameRequired = 'Name is required!';
    const emailRequired = 'Email is required!';
    const emailNotValid = 'Email is wrong!';
    const mobileRequired = 'Mobile is required!';

    const employeeData = req.body;
    // Start Validation
    req.checkBody('employeeName', nameRequired).notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('employeeEmail', emailRequired).notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('employeeEmail', emailNotValid).isEmail();
    req.checkBody('employeeMobile', mobileRequired).notEmpty();

    req.sanitize('employeeName').trim();
    req.sanitize('employeeName').escape();
    // End Validation
    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    console.log(errors);
    if(!errors){
        const employee = new Employee({
            name : req.body.employeeName,
            email : req.body.employeeEmail,
            mobile : req.body.employeemobile,
        });
        employee.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('User inserted successfully');
            res.redirect('/employee-list');
        });
    }else{
        console.log(employeeData.employeeName);
        const employeeNameRequired = errors.find(el => el === nameRequired );
        const employeeEmailRequired = errors.find(el => el === emailRequired);
        const employeeEmailNotValid = errors.find(el => el === emailNotValid);
        const employeeMobileRequired = errors.find(el => el === mobileRequired);

        res.render('employee/add-employee',{
            employeeData,
            employeeNameRequired,
            employeeEmailRequired,
            employeeEmailNotValid,
            employeeMobileRequired
        });
    }
};
```

And you View file will look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Add Employee Profile</h3>
            <h5 class='text-aqua pull-right' style='margin-top: 0px;'>
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='' class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>&nbsp;Back</a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method = 'post' action = '/save-employee'>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                        <input type='text' name='employeeName' id='employeeName' value='<%= employeeData.employeeName %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Name'>
                        <p><%= employeeNameRequired %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <span class="help-block" style="text-align:center" id="error_tagType"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 
                        <input type='text' name='employeeEmail' id='employeeEmail' value='<%= employeeData.employeeEmail %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Email'>
                        <p><%= employeeEmailRequired %></p>
                        <p><%= employeeEmailNotValid %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <span class="help-block" style="text-align:center" id="error_tagName"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Mobile</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 
                        <input type='text' name='employeeMobile' id='employeeMobile' value='<%= employeeData.employeeMobile %>' class='form-control' placeholder='Employee Mobile'>
                        <p><%= employeeMobileRequired %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <span class="help-block" style="text-align:center" id="error_tagDescription"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="callout" id='message-container' style='display:none;'></div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type='submit' name='saveEmployeeProfile' class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
For me personally, using [jsonSchema](http://json-schema.org/) validation fits best. It's very configurable and results in more readable code. For example module [tv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4) can be used with jsonSchema to validate `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Lazyexpert, Please suggest me how to manage this error in view file.

1. if user is pass some value on form then retail old value in input field.
2. if user fill new form then  show form blank.

Comment: Thank you Lazyexpert. :)

Comment: @RajeevVarshney I've added view file, more accurate solution would be to check if, for example `employeeEmailRequired` exists - only then show error. But I'm not very much familiar with ejs.

Comment: can you suggest that why i am using this & what is el ? const employeeNameRequired = errors.find(el => el === nameRequired );

Comment: It's es6 arrow function. We find in errors array fitting error:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions